# how to create a gpo that installs an .exe file

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, group-policy, installation

I'd like to automate the creation and deployment of a GPO on an AD's client machines. It's based on windows server 2012.

```
curl file.exe
Move-Item file.exe path
New-GPO -Name nameofgpo -Comment "Let's move"

#i would like to install file.exe with this GPO created
```

Do you have some idea ? Thanks

I can' t really find anything on the internet

Comment: You want to let client **maschines** create wild GPO in your domain? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be help you to copy an EXE file to domain computers.
[GPO to create subfolder and copy file](https://serverfault.com/questions/727105/gpo-to-create-subfolder-and-copy-file)